# Multiple textfields value updation with multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I am having 1 text field with number of buttons each having value of their own.

In the code below as i have a single input field i have used it to update the value based on button value to the input field id.
How can i know the which input field i have selected before the button click to pass the button value to the input field when there are multiple input fields??

```js
var x,y;
    function first(){
        var y=1;
        document.getElementById("how").value=y;
        }
    
    function second(){
        var x=2;
        document.getElementById("how").value=x;
        }
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="first()" value="1" id="01"/>
    <input type="button" onclick="second()" value="2" id="02"/>
    <input type="text" value="" id="how"/>
```

Let me know how this can be achieved in the easiest way

Comment: Perhaps you can use `onfocus` event?

Comment: I am not very sure what you are trying to accomplish but you may want to add the eventhandler function to the textbox itself.

Comment: @Umair any code you can help me with would be really helpful. Hoping you understood what i want to achieve here

Comment: Can you use jQuery?

Comment: @MerakMarey i do have some understanding of jquery but im new so a snippet would be helpful.

Comment: @fireindhole Let me ask you this..What you intend to do is simply to put in the text the value you have on the button element?

Comment: @fireindhole I agree with Eric's answer below. I think this is what you want. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a single onfocus function for each of the inputs, and have it store a global reference of the last focused input. Then use the global reference in your button click functions.

Code example:

```
<input type="button" onclick="first()" value="1" id="01"/>
<input type="button" onclick="second()" value="2" id="02"/>
<input type="text" onfocus="inputFocus(this)" value="" id="input1"/>
<input type="text" onfocus="inputFocus(this)" value="" id="input2"/>  
<input type="text" onfocus="inputFocus(this)" value="" id="input3"/>      
<script>

var x,y;
var focusObj;

function first(){
    var y=1;
    if(focusObj) focusObj.value = y;
}

function second(){
    var x=2;
    if(focusObj) focusObj.value = x;
}

function inputFocus(obj) {
   focusObj = obj;
}

</script>
```

Comment: Aplogies for the late reply , it worked thanks Eric.